# LINQ to SQL Add CASE STATEMENT then original field NOT FOUND

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Here is my original LINQ, very simple.

```
var participant = (from p in context.Participants
                       select p);
```

Works fine until I add the case statement to it.

```
var participant = (from p in context.Participants
                       select new
                       {
                          p,
                          Eligibility =
                          (
                            p.IsEligible == 1 ? "Eligible" :
                            p.IsEligible == 0 ? "Ineligible" : "Pending"
                          )
                      });
```

On the GridView DataBind() method, it throw exception said pID(in Participants table) not found.
I check the SQL command text on the debug mode, it does has the Participant object.
Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because your query no longer returns instances of `Participant`: it returns instances of an *anonymous* class with two members - `p` and `Eligibility`; there is no `pId` among the members of the anonymous class, hence the error that you are seeing.

I would try binding to `p.pId`, or better yet, give `p` a more meaningful name, say, `Participant`, like this:

```
select new {
    Participant = p,
    Eligibility = ... // and so on
}
```

Then your binding would be more readable.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, the anonymous class make sense to me. I add the `Participant = p` part, but when I bind it. it still say Participant.pID not found. BTW, I bind it to the gridview by this `DataTextField="Participant.pID"`

Comment: @DeshengLi I did not realize that you were binding to GridView (I thought you were on the WPF/XAML stack, where binding to property of a property is possible). One thing you can do is to "call out" the properties that you need to bind from the `Participant`, if the list is not too long, like this: `select new {pId = p.pId, pName = p.Name, Eligibility=...}`.

Comment: All right, Thank you @dasblinkenlight! 
And also I want to point out why I can't bind to the GridView.
The controls like asp:BoundField, asp:ButtonField do not support DataBinding Event, so we can not use like `Eval("Participant.pID")` for them.
We need to switch to the asp:TemplateField and put a asp:label in it to do to nested binding.

Comment: But my solution is, adding a rowdatabound event to the GridView.
    `protected void gvParticipant_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    dynamic item = e.Row.DataItem as dynamic;
                    ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text = item.Participant.pID.ToString();
                }
            }`

I took advantage of the dynamic type and it works well!!

Comment: It does not let me answer my own question. TOT

Comment: @DeshengLi I am glad that it worked out well. One thing to note is that the data binding question is separate from the data acquisition question, so posting it separately and with different tags *could* have given you a faster turnaround. On the other hand, I am sure that figuring out an answer independently was of more value to you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have created an anonymous object consisting of two members; "p" (a Participant) and "Eligibility" (a string).

If the. Binding can handle nested binding, then bind to "p.Id" etc. better: create a view-model for the members you want.